# Specto Missing from Debian 11

Tags: debian, monitoring

I once had this package called [specto](https://sources.debian.org/src/specto/), that would monitor a website for changes. Now, it seems to be missing in Debian 11:

```
▶sudo apt install specto
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package specto
```

I'm curious why it is no longer available, and if there's an AppImage for it (or some other way I can still install it).

Comment: I found [this](http://specto.sourceforge.net/). I wonder why it is no longer in the repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s no longer available because [it depends on the obsolete `gnome-python` library](https://bugs.debian.org/886054) (and more generally, the obsolete Python 2 ecosystem); it was removed from Debian in January 2018 and isn’t available in either Debian 10 or Debian 11. This is actually a long time after Specto’s own author [declared it obsolete, in March 2013](http://web.archive.org/web/20180717233304/http://fortintam.com/blog/2013/03/21/a-programs-obsolescence/)!

I doubt there’s an AppImage for it. You could always run it in a Debian 9 container, but even if you managed to get the notifications hooked up to your main desktop environment, I’m not sure the old notification system used by Specto would work any more.

When Specto’s author declared it obsolete, the idea — at least for monitoring web sites — was to use Liferea (or another similar syndication-feed-based tool), but even that idea is largely obsolete nowadays (unfortunately).

Comment: Do you happen to have a recommendation? I'm guessing curl or wget could do this with some scripting. I'm only really wanting to monitor changes in the html. I'm taking a look at Liferea now.

Comment: I’m afraid I don’t.